# DOM - Select Value from a Field that has a Search Component and a Drop Down

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom

I have been working on this forever. I have attached a first picture of the steps I am trying to do in VBA. This particular field that I have having trouble populating for a client of mine appears to be a drop down but when you click it, it has a search field. I know the option value I want the field to be set to but using doc.getElementbyID("id_referrer").selectedIndex = fieldValue is not working. See the first picture for the steps of what I'm trying to do, then the second picture for the behind the scenes look at the classes and then all the different commands that I've tried to populate this field. The save button works, but nothing ever is populated for the Referrer or it bombs.

[image: firstpicture]
[image: secondpicture]

Comment: Jennifer, I hate to be the party pooper, but you might need to entertain the possibility that this isn't VBA.

Comment: Difficult to really address this without a URL to work with.  There could be all sorts of scripting in the background reacting to user actions and setting hidden fields etc etc.

Comment: Thanks. I have already been performing multiple 'writes' to different fields on a big implementation project, however, this one particular field was giving me trouble. The url is password protected and I can't give the login away. Unfortunately, I don't really know anything other than VBA, but it's helped me do the rest of the project ok. My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that it's not really a dropdown, when you click the arrow, it is not a list - you have to type something to search first, then the only things that show up are what you start typing.